# Submitting hcaptcha captcha token to Discord to create an account using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, discord, captcha, 2captcha

I am using python selenium to create a Discord account (https://discord.com/register), but it is protected with a hcaptcha. I have a captcha API (2captcha/capmonster) to return a captcha token and putting it into the `g-captcha-response textarea`. Normally there is a submit button that you would click afterwards which would then allow you to the site (if the captcha token is correct), but Discord automatically redirects you once you manually complete the hcaptcha. I am assuming that Discord is using the hcaptcha callback function. but I have had no luck finding the callback function so I can call it once I put in the captcha token.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```py
import random
import requests
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


email = "example@gmail.com"
username = "exampleusername"
password = "examplepassword"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://discord.com/register')
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys(email) # email
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(username) # username
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password) # password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div').click()

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1, 12))) # Month
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1, 28))) # Day
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.send_keys(str(random.randint(1989, 2000))) # Year
actions.perform()

try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputDefault-3JxKJ2').click()  # Agree to terms and conditions
except:
    pass
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-3k0cO7').click()  # Submit button


# get captcha key
site_key = 'f5561ba9-8f1e-40ca-9b5b-a0b3f719ef34'
url = "https://discordapp.com/register"
API_KEY = "CAPMONSTER API KEY"
s = requests.Session()
data_post = {
    "clientKey": API_KEY,
    "task":
        {
            "type": "HCaptchaTaskProxyless",
            "websiteURL": url,
            "websiteKey": site_key
        }
}
captcha_id = s.post("https://api.capmonster.cloud/createTask", json=data_post).json()
data_get = {
    "clientKey": API_KEY,
    "taskId": captcha_id['taskId']
}
captcha_answer = s.get("https://api.capmonster.cloud/getTaskResult", json=data_get).json()
while captcha_answer['status'] == "processing":
    time.sleep(5)
    captcha_answer = s.get("https://api.capmonster.cloud/getTaskResult", json=data_get).json()
captcha_token = captcha_answer["solution"]["gRecaptchaResponse"]
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].innerText="{captcha_token}";') # put captcha token into g-recaptcha-response textarea
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("h-captcha-response")[0].innerText="{captcha_token}";')

# code to submit captcha token
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to submitting the bypass token?

Comment: No I still haven't

Comment: Any update on this? still looking

Comment: Nope. I kind of gave up since I couldn't find anything

Comment: Anyone find a solution for that?

Comment: no updates still?

Comment: Smbd have solution?

Answer (score 0):

i found a way which works fine for me.
You don't need any captchasolver for hcaptcha as they have a accessibility cookie, which when inserted into the webpage solve captchas instantly.
Note that this is not created by me, just wanted to share it to help you guys out.
https://github.com/avengy/hcaptcha-bypass-discord

edit: In case the Link is invalid later on, here the essential parts:

## hcaptcha-bypass-discord

Bypass HCAPTCHA purely based on http requests Works for discord dosen't create locked accounts :))

**HOW TO USE**

◉ add the hcapbypass.py in your project

◉ "from hcapbypass import bypass" at top of your main file

◉ to solve captcha call the function

-> bypass(sitekey, "discord.com", proxy="ip:port")
or
bypass(sitekey, "discord.com", proxy="username:pass@ip:port")

**Why release this?**

i had a deal with a femboy named woen for 150$ but he decided to scam me hes cheap af! so if a scammer can have this why not yall enjoy :))

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
import math
import base64
import httpx
import urllib
import hashlib
from json import dumps
import json
import os
import random

headers = {
    "Host": "hcaptcha.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "sec-ch-ua": 'Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92',
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Origin": "https://newassets.hcaptcha.com",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"

}

def N_Data(req) -> str:
        try:
            """
            this part takes the req value inside the getsiteconfig and converts it into our hash, we need this for the final step.
            (thanks to h0nde for this function btw, you can find the original code for this at the top of the file.)
            """
            x = "0123456789/:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

            req = req.split(".")

            req = {
                "header": json.loads(
                    base64.b64decode(
                        req[0] +
                        "=======").decode("utf-8")),
                "payload": json.loads(
                    base64.b64decode(
                        req[1] +
                        "=======").decode("utf-8")),
                "raw": {
                    "header": req[0],
                    "payload": req[1],
                    "signature": req[2]}}

            def a(r):
                for t in range(len(r) - 1, -1, -1):
                    if r[t] < len(x) - 1:
                        r[t] += 1
                        return True
                    r[t] = 0
                return False

            def i(r):
                t = ""
                for n in range(len(r)):
                    t += x[r[n]]
                return t

            def o(r, e):
                n = e
                hashed = hashlib.sha1(e.encode())
                o = hashed.hexdigest()
                t = hashed.digest()
                e = None
                n = -1
                o = []
                for n in range(n + 1, 8 * len(t)):
                    e = t[math.floor(n / 8)] >> n % 8 & 1
                    o.append(e)
                a = o[:r]

                def index2(x, y):
                    if y in x:
                        return x.index(y)
                    return -1
                return 0 == a[0] and index2(a, 1) >= r - 1 or -1 == index2(a, 1)

            def get():
                for e in range(25):
                    n = [0 for i in range(e)]
                    while a(n):
                        u = req["payload"]["d"] + "::" + i(n)
                        if o(req["payload"]["s"], u):
                            return i(n)

            result = get()
            hsl = ":".join([
                "1",
                str(req["payload"]["s"]),
                datetime.now().isoformat()[:19]
                .replace("T", "")
                .replace("-", "")
                .replace(":", ""),
                req["payload"]["d"],
                "",
                result
            ])
            return hsl
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False

def REQ_Data(host, sitekey,proxy):
        try:
            r = httpx.get(f"https://hcaptcha.com/checksiteconfig?host={host}&sitekey={sitekey}&sc=1&swa=1", headers=headers,proxies={"https://": f"http://{proxy}"},timeout=4)
            if r.json()["pass"]:
                return r.json()["c"]
            else:
                return False
        except :
            return False

def Get_Captcha(host, sitekey, n, req,proxy):
        try:
            json = {
                "sitekey": sitekey,
                "v": "b1129b9",
                "host": host,
                "n": n,
                'motiondata': '{"st":1628923867722,"mm":[[203,16,1628923874730],[155,42,1628923874753],[137,53,1628923874770],[122,62,1628923874793],[120,62,1628923875020],[107,62,1628923875042],[100,61,1628923875058],[93,60,1628923875074],[89,59,1628923875090],[88,59,1628923875106],[87,59,1628923875131],[87,59,1628923875155],[84,56,1628923875171],[76,51,1628923875187],[70,47,1628923875203],[65,44,1628923875219],[63,42,1628923875235],[62,41,1628923875251],[61,41,1628923875307],[58,39,1628923875324],[54,38,1628923875340],[49,36,1628923875363],[44,36,1628923875380],[41,35,1628923875396],[40,35,1628923875412],[38,35,1628923875428],[38,35,1628923875444],[37,35,1628923875460],[37,35,1628923875476],[37,35,1628923875492]],"mm-mp":13.05084745762712,"md":[[37,35,1628923875529]],"md-mp":0,"mu":[[37,35,1628923875586]],"mu-mp":0,"v":1,"topLevel":{"st":1628923867123,"sc":{"availWidth":1680,"availHeight":932,"width":1680,"height":1050,"colorDepth":30,"pixelDepth":30,"availLeft":0,"availTop":23},"nv":{"vendorSub":"","productSub":"20030107","vendor":"Google Inc.","maxTouchPoints":0,"userActivation":{},"doNotTrack":null,"geolocation":{},"connection":{},"webkitTemporaryStorage":{},"webkitPersistentStorage":{},"hardwareConcurrency":12,"cookieEnabled":true,"appCodeName":"Mozilla","appName":"Netscape","appVersion":"5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36","platform":"MacIntel","product":"Gecko","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36","language":"en-US","languages":["en-US","en"],"onLine":true,"webdriver":false,"serial":{},"scheduling":{},"xr":{},"mediaCapabilities":{},"permissions":{},"locks":{},"usb":{},"mediaSession":{},"clipboard":{},"credentials":{},"keyboard":{},"mediaDevices":{},"storage":{},"serviceWorker":{},"wakeLock":{},"deviceMemory":8,"hid":{},"presentation":{},"userAgentData":{},"bluetooth":{},"managed":{},"plugins":["internal-pdf-viewer","mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai","internal-nacl-plugin"]},"dr":"https://discord.com/","inv":false,"exec":false,"wn":[[1463,731,2,1628923867124],[733,731,2,1628923871704]],"wn-mp":4580,"xy":[[0,0,1,1628923867125]],"xy-mp":0,"mm":[[1108,233,1628923867644],[1110,230,1628923867660],[1125,212,1628923867678],[1140,195,1628923867694],[1158,173,1628923867711],[1179,152,1628923867727],[1199,133,1628923867744],[1221,114,1628923867768],[1257,90,1628923867795],[1272,82,1628923867811],[1287,76,1628923867827],[1299,71,1628923867844],[1309,68,1628923867861],[1315,66,1628923867877],[1326,64,1628923867894],[1331,62,1628923867911],[1336,60,1628923867927],[1339,58,1628923867944],[1343,56,1628923867961],[1345,54,1628923867978],[1347,53,1628923867994],[1348,52,1628923868011],[1350,51,1628923868028],[1354,49,1628923868045],[1366,44,1628923868077],[1374,41,1628923868094],[1388,36,1628923868110],[1399,31,1628923868127],[1413,25,1628923868144],[1424,18,1628923868161],[1436,10,1628923868178],[1445,3,1628923868195],[995,502,1628923871369],[722,324,1628923874673],[625,356,1628923874689],[523,397,1628923874705],[457,425,1628923874721]],"mm-mp":164.7674418604651},"session":[],"widgetList":["0a1l5c3yudk4"],"widgetId":"0a1l5c3yudk4","href":"https://discord.com/register","prev":{"escaped":false,"passed":false,"expiredChallenge":false,"expiredResponse":false}}',
                "hl": "en",
                "c": dumps(req)
            }

            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(json)
            headers = {
                "Host": "hcaptcha.com",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "sec-ch-ua": 'Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92',
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
                "Content-length": str(len(data)),
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36",
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Origin": "https://newassets.hcaptcha.com",
                "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
                "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                "Referer": "https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"

            }

            cookies = {"hc_accessibility": "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UCa12gEu9VIPScd9"}
            r = httpx.post(f"https://hcaptcha.com/getcaptcha?s={sitekey}",cookies=cookies, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=4,proxies={"https://": f"http://{proxy}"})

            return r.json()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False

def bypass(sitekey, host,proxy):
    try :
        req = REQ_Data(sitekey=sitekey, host=host,proxy=proxy)
        req["type"] = "hsl"
        n = N_Data(req["req"])
        res = Get_Captcha(sitekey=sitekey, host=host,proxy=proxy,n=n, req=req)
        if "generated_pass_UUID" in res:
            captcha = res["generated_pass_UUID"]
            return captcha
        else:
            return False
    except : return False
```

**If you using this in your project and releasing it on github then credit the right people below**

Credits:

- Aniell4 for orignal source https://github.com/Aniell4
- Avenger for modifying the code to fix lock acc issue

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31904581)